# Return splitted list from loop "while" Python, Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, while-loop, split

In my application, I have a table with users but the table can have more than 1 page with users. I want to get a list with all users in all pages with Selenium Webdriver Python. I have test function which goes to the first page, gets a list with all users then goes to the second page gets a list of users and until the pages no longer exist:

```
def test_users1(driver):
    login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
    while True:
         try:
            #gets list of elements
            userslist = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".even .odd")
            #goes to second page, third...etc.
            for i in range(1, 50):
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()
         except NoSuchElementException:
            break
         return (userslist)
```

I need to return split list with all users from all pages from my loop

Comment: add `userslist += driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()` if `driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()` returns the list of user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use list extend method

```
def test_users1(driver):
    login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
    userslist = []
    while True:
        try:
            #gets list of elements
            userslist.extend(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".even .odd"))
            #goes to second page, third...etc.
            for i in range(1, 50):
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()
                userslist.extend(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".even .odd"))
                # Add new line here ^^^^
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    return (userslist)
```

Comment: may be this:  
`assert (len(userslist) == YOUINT), "Wrong users list"`

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5b274w61sokdeqv/Screenshot%202017-07-29%2016.17.28.png?dl=0)
I don't know why but it returns me Sized type not int

Answer (score 0):

```
def users1(driver):
    userslist = []
    while True:
        try:
            #gets list of elements
            userslist.extend(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".even .odd"))
            #goes to second page, third...etc.
            for i in range(1, 50):
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    return userslist


def test_users1(driver):
    login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
    users = users1(driver)
    assert len(users) == 63
```

Comment: @Bear Brown I found decision, thank you so much for help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45394732/6939940

Comment: I'm glad to help a little.

Comment: @Bear Brown I'm sorry I thought it works but it doesn't, the algorithm is right but the lists don't splitting, always return result 50 which is from just 1 page

Comment: I add a new line to your algorithm try it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392369/return-splitted-list-from-loop-while-python-selenium?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I'm glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
def users1(driver):
userslist = []
while True:
    try:
        #gets list of elements
        userslist.extend(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody tr"))
        #goes to second page, third...etc.
        for i in range(1, 50):
            driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
return len(userslist)

def test_users1(driver):
login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
assert users1(driver) == 50
```